# PHP require_once and paths

Tags: php, path, require-once

I inherited a PHP app that's been developed in Eclipse.  While familiarizing myself with the code I noticed something odd.  A little background.  There are 2 code projects that share Common code.  Each of these 3 are at the same directory level.  The two projects have a softlink that points to common code.  While reviewing various files, I noticed two different methods of including a file.

```
require_once 'common/utils/DatabaseClasses.php';
ahd
require_once '../common/utils/DatabaseClasses.php';
```

Is there a difference?  Advantages/disadvantages?  Eclipse will autocomplete the first method.  Aside from that, I don't notice a difference.  Also, there are no namespaces used in this app.  Not sure if that's relevant here or not.

This is how the dirs/links are organized.

```
Project1
    |------------- ../Common
Project2
    |------------- ../Common
Common
```

Comment: Is there a symbolic link "common", in one of the project, that would point to `../common`?

If not, I don't see how the project with `common` would resolve the classes in the common project.

Comment: `there are no namespaces used in this app. Not sure if that's relevant here or not`....no. Namespaces and physical file paths are not related to each other.

Comment: Maybe it depends on the hierarchy of included files: if the entry point is A and A includes B which includes C, for C the path is relative to A. Instead if the entry point is B and B includes C, for C the path is relative to B

Comment: There is a symbolic link 'common' that points to '../common' in each of the projects.

Answer (score 2):

[From the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) there is a difference if you have set a `include_path` in your PHP configuration (php.ini file):

`require_once 'common/utils/DatabaseClasses.php';` will try first to find the file in the `include_path` if it is set, then in the script directory and last in the current working directory.

If an absolute or relative path is used like in `require_once '../common/utils/DatabaseClasses.php';`, the `include_path` search will be ignored.

So because the "generic" `common` folder is out of the projects folders, there's a strong chance that the `include_path` is set to its value, or else I don't see how these files would be included without pointing explicitly to it from the parent folder or from the root (as pointed in the comments). So I guess the first version is designed to point to the "generic" folder while the second points to the project's one. This is just a supposition, you have to check your configuration